# Rules for parentheses in SQL. Does not seem to be working

Tags: sql, parentheses

New to SQL.  Having issues with "Like '%" and "not like '%" statements returning incorrect values.  I think it's the parentheses.  When I use the following, I'm still seeing "YMCA" and "United Way" even though I'm selecting them out.  I've tried nesting the individual parentheses into one big parentheses, I've tried putting individual parentheses around each statement.  Nothing is working.  Here is the code.  Any advice is much appreciated!

```
SELECT TRANSACTION_DATE, MERCHANT_NAME 
FROM CardTrans 
WHERE 
   (
     (TRANSACTION_DATE BETWEEN '2018-03-01' AND  '2018-03-15') 
     OR 
     (    TRANSACTION_DATE IS NULL 
      AND POST_DATE BETWEEN '2018-03-01' AND '2018-03-15')
   ) 
AND (TRANSACTION_BASE_TYPE = 'debit') 
and  (DESCRIPTION LIKE '%SWAIR%') 
OR   (DESCRIPTION LIKE '%SW AIR%') 
OR   (DESCRIPTION LIKE '%SWA INFL%') 
OR   (DESCRIPTION LIKE '%*Southwest Air%') 
AND   DESCRIPTION NOT LIKE '%AMAZON%' 
AND   DESCRIPTION NOT LIKE '%AMZ%' 
AND   DESCRIPTION NOT LIKE '%YMCA OF SOUTHWES%' 
AND   DESCRIPTION NOT LIKE '%UNITED WAY OF SOUTHWES%' 
ORDER BY DESCRIPTION;
GO
```

Comment: I reformatted/indented your query so we can actually see what the parentheses do. I'm not sure about the AND/OR order, so maybe there is your problem.

Comment: Please add sample data, desired oputput and wrong result you currently get. *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.*

Answer (score 3):

I am guessing you want:

```
WHERE ( (TRANSACTION_DATE BETWEEN '2018-03-01' AND  '2018-03-15') OR 
        (TRANSACTION_DATE IS NULL AND POST_DATE BETWEEN '2018-03-01' AND '2018-03-15')
      ) AND
      TRANSACTION_BASE_TYPE = 'debit' AND  
      (DESCRIPTION LIKE '%SWAIR%' OR
       DESCRIPTION LIKE '%SW AIR%' OR
       DESCRIPTION LIKE '%SWA INFL%' OR 
       DESCRIPTION LIKE '%*Southwest Air%'
      ) AND
      DESCRIPTION NOT LIKE '%AMAZON%' AND 
      DESCRIPTION NOT LIKE '%AMZ%' AND 
      DESCRIPTION NOT LIKE '%YMCA OF SOUTHWES%' AND 
      DESCRIPTION NOT LIKE '%UNITED WAY OF SOUTHWES%'
```

Your problem is understanding the precedence rules for `AND` and `OR`.  `AND` has higher precedence, so:

```
 DESCRIPTION LIKE '%SWA INFL%' OR 
 DESCRIPTION LIKE '%*Southwest Air%' AND
 DESCRIPTION NOT LIKE '%AMAZON%'
```

Is parsed as:

```
 DESCRIPTION LIKE '%SWA INFL%' OR 
 (DESCRIPTION LIKE '%*Southwest Air%' AND
  DESCRIPTION NOT LIKE '%AMAZON%'
 )
```

And you might see `AMAZON` in the results.

Answer (score 0):

You have a series of `AND`s that do exclude `'%YMCA OF SOUTHWES%'` as well as `'%UNITED WAY OF SOUTHWES%'`
but you also have these `OR`s:

```
    ...  OR
   (DESCRIPTION LIKE '%SW AIR%') OR
   (DESCRIPTION LIKE '%SWA INFL%') OR 
   (DESCRIPTION LIKE '%*Southwest Air%')
```

that could let the excluded items back in, if `DESCRIPTION` contains them.

Answer (score -1):

This is your query removing all the parenthesis not needed

```
SELECT TRANSACTION_DATE, MERCHANT_NAME 
FROM CardTrans 
WHERE (
 TRANSACTION_DATE BETWEEN '2018-03-01' AND  '2018-03-15'           
    OR 
  TRANSACTION_DATE IS NULL 
  AND POST_DATE BETWEEN '2018-03-01' AND '2018-03-15'
       )     
AND TRANSACTION_BASE_TYPE = 'debit'
and DESCRIPTION LIKE '%SWAIR%'
OR DESCRIPTION LIKE '%SW AIR%' 
OR DESCRIPTION LIKE '%SWA INFL%'
OR DESCRIPTION LIKE '%*Southwest Air%'
AND DESCRIPTION NOT LIKE '%AMAZON%' 
AND DESCRIPTION NOT LIKE '%AMZ%' 
AND DESCRIPTION NOT LIKE '%YMCA OF SOUTHWES%' 
AND DESCRIPTION NOT LIKE '%UNITED WAY OF SOUTHWES%' 
ORDER BY DESCRIPTION; GO
```

Remember AND are done before OR so 1 OR 2 AND 2 is TRUE -> (2AND2)OR1

Comment: So this way `YMCA` won't be filtered out, because there is an `OR` saying I take everything as long as there is a `SW_AIR` or a `SWA INFL` or a `Southwest Air`

Comment: That's how is written, I just removed the 'excess' of parentesis.

Comment: Yes, but the question is why that what's written does not work. Removing redudant parentheses doesn't make a wrong query work.

Comment: I wrote Why the query does not work, once OP knows the rule can figure out how to fix, otherweise he'd better to post sample data, desired output and wrong output